# local variable initialization problem in if-else (Java)

Tags: java, if-statement, initialization

This is my code.

```
public class Test {
    public void main (String[] args) {

        int a;
        String b = "11343468/32145";

        String c[] = b.split("");

        for(int i=0; i<c.length; i++) {
            if(c[i].equals("/")) {
                a = i;
            } else {a = 0;}
        }
        System.out.println(a);
    }
```

I'm trying to find the index of `/` in `String[] c`.

But when printing `a`, eclipse said **The local variable a may not have been initialized.**

I know I can print `a` if I put `System.out.println(a);` in `if-else {}`, but I have more works to do on this code so I must use printing code outside `if-else`.

I used `else` code but still have an error. What's the problem?

Comment: The compiler doesn't know that the length of the array `c` is guaranteed to be greater than zero. It therefore doesn't know whether for-loop will be entered. If it isn't, the variable is never initialised.

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialize variable value while declaring in method.
You can find the code below, There is different ways to do the same.Below in one of them.

```
public class Test {
    public static void main (String[] args) {

        int a = -1;
        String b = "11343468/32145";

        String c[] = b.split("");

        for(int i=0; i<c.length; i++) {
            if(c[i].equals("/")) {
                a = i;
                break;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(a);
    }
}
```

Comment: what if: String b = "/1345";  It will be unclear if / was found in the string, or if 0 was printed because of the initial value of b.

Answer (score 1):

Like already mentioned in the comments, the compiler's analysis does not go far enough that it can guarantee the for-loop ever runs, and therefore the variable is not ["definitely assigned" as required by the language](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-16.html).

To find the index of a character in a string, you don't need for loops or if statements. You can just use the `indexOf` method:

```
    String b = "11343468/32145";
    int a = b.indexOf('/');
```

Answer (score 0):

@Michael's comment is correct, if you modify your code like this, the message will go away:

```
public class Test {
    private static final NOT_FOUND = -1;
    public void main (String[] args) {

        int a = NOT_FOUND;
        String b = "11343468/32145";

        String c[] = b.split("");

        for(int i=0; i<c.length; i++) {
            if(c[i].equals("/")) {
                a = i;
            } else {a = 0;}
        }
        System.out.println((a == NOT_FOUND ? "NOT_FOUND" : a);
    }
}
```

The constant NOT_FOUND is unnecessary, but it clarifies what is happening. Keep in mind that continuing your loop after you've found "/" will likely overwrite the "found" value of a.

Comment: But there is no point in looping here: you may as well only check the last character.

Comment: @AndyTurner you are correct, however I wasn't intending to solve the _whole_ problem for the OP. The OP's request was for assistance in addressing the error message from the compiler. Notice my closing sentence in my post.

Answer (score 0):

I assume a is printing as 0 in your case, even if you initialize the variable a . its because using else you are always making it 0 at the end .
please use something like this:

```
    int a = 0;
    String b = "11343468/32145";
    String c[] = b.split("");
    for (int i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
        if (c[i].equals("/")) {
            a = i;
            break;
        } else {
            a = 0;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("the value is" + a);
```

Answer (score 0):

I will take a different approach. From code org point of view, fetching the index should be a separate operation, which would be rather a function. So your code will be

```
public class Test {
    public static void getIndex (String str, String match) {
        String c[] = str.split("");
        for(int i=0; i<c.length; i++) {
            if(c[i].equals(match)) {
                return i;
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

In case you want last index, then

```
public class Test {

    public static void getIndex (String str) {
        int index = -1;
        String c[] = str.split("");
        for(int i=0; i<c.length; i++) {
            if(c[i].equals(match)) {
                index = i;
            }
        }
        return index; 
    }
}
```

And then use the same in main

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
    String b = "11343468/32145";
    System.out.println(getIndex(b, "/"));
}
```

Also if you are using java, then you have two functions available in String class - `String::indexOf` and `String::lastIndexOf`. If you don't want ot use that, you have an option to use `String::toCharArray()`. Using `String::split` for this purpose is highly discouraged!

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

For you to be able to print `a` it must be initialised. In your code the complier doesn't know that the `for` loop will be executed.

One quick way to solve this is to set `a` to null by using the following:

```
Integer a = null; // note we are using the object not the primitive int
```